# dayofyear to NSDate objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, dayofweek

Simple question. I have some dirty solutions but couldn't figure out a clean, robust one. The problem is I have the dayofyear (from SQL Server), I want to convert it to NSDate. In detail:

```
int dayofyear = 205  //I have this 

NSDate* date =  ??something by adding dayofyear to 1/1/currentyear(2013)??

//must have :  date = 07/25/2013
```

Thanks

arda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get "start of current year":

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfYear;
[cal rangeOfUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfYear interval:NULL
         forDate:now];
// startOfYear represents now the start of the current year.
```

Add 205 days:

```
int dayofyear = 205;
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comp setDay:dayofyear];
NSDate *newDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:comp toDate:startOfYear options:0];
```

Comment: +1 for getting start date of calendar unit. I had no idea about this method, thanks! :-)

Comment: @LukasKukacka: Yes, that is very convenient. Using the `interval` parameter you get also the end of the period, e.g. start/end date of current day.

Comment: Haven't implemented yet but looks perfect. Thank you!